# Can "PropertyChanged Event" of Xamarin bindable behavior directly handle property of its view?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, behavior

I want to handle the properties of the view with bindable behavior.

Is there any method to access directly to the view that is connected within the event handler?

Changing the "AssociatedObject" to static causes problems with binding.

What should I do?

```js
public class CustNameBehavior : Behavior<Label>
{
    public Label AssociatedObject { get; private set; }

    public static readonly BindableProperty MyNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MyName), typeof(string), typeof(CustNameBehavior), null, BindingMode.OneWay, propertyChanged: OnMyNameChanged);
    private static void OnMyNameChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        CustNameBehavior target = (CustNameBehavior)bindable;

        if (target != null)
        {
            var value = (string)newValue;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {
                AssociatedObject.Text = "Empty!";   => this is inaccessible. because of non static.
            }
            else
            {
                AssociatedObject.Text = value;   => this is inaccessible. because of non static.
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Label bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        AssociatedObject = bindable;
        bindable.BindingContextChanged += Bindable_BindingContextChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Label bindable)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
        bindable.BindingContextChanged -= Bindable_BindingContextChanged;
        AssociatedObject = null;
    }

    private void Bindable_BindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        BindingContext = AssociatedObject.BindingContext;
    }

    public string MyName
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(MyNameProperty);
        set
        {
            SetValue(MyNameProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in the behaviour? If you could tell me that I think we can do it quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OnMyNameChanged` handler has to be static, because `MyNameProperty` is too (well, maybe it's feasible, technically, but it would be brittle and jumping through hoops). Anyway, you'd want `AssociatedObject` to be non-static, because you need one per instance of `CustNameBehavior`, anything else would likely not behave as intended.

However, you *can* access non-static methods and properties from `OnMyNameChanged` because the instance of `CustNameBehavior` is passed via the `bindable` parameter. Furthermore, this instance holds a reference to a `Label` via `AssociatedObject`. Hence you can access `AssociatedObject` via `target` (the `bindable` that has already been cast to `CustNameBehavior`), hence your method would become

```cs
private static void OnMyNameChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    CustNameBehavior target = (CustNameBehavior)bindable;

    if (target != null && target.AssociatedObject != null)
    {
        var value = (string)newValue;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            target.AssociatedObject.Text = "Empty!"; 
        }
        else
        {
            target.AssociatedObject.Text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Please note** that I've added a check for `AssociatedObject` being `null`, because I assume `OnMyNameChanged` being called before the behavior is bound.

IMHO it would be even better if you moved the instance logic to a method on its own right

```cs
private static void OnMyNameChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    CustNameBehavior target = (CustNameBehavior)bindable;
    target?.SetLabelName((string)newValue);
}

private void SetLabelName(string name)
{
    if(AssociatedObject != null)
    {
        AssociatedObject.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? "Empty!" : name;
    }
}
```

You'll furthermore have to set `AssociatedObject.Text` from `OnAttachedTo`, because `MyNameProperty` won't be set at the time being, which would cause `AssociatedObject.Text` to not being updated. You could reuse `SetLabelName` for that purpose, this way, you won't have to duplicate the logic that checks for the string being empty.

```cs
protected override void OnAttachedTo(Label bindable)
{
    base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
    AssociatedObject = bindable;
    SetLabelName((string)GetValue(MyNameProperty));
    bindable.BindingContextChanged += Bindable_BindingContextChanged;
}
```